# How to subscript a text on a spinner in Android?

Tags: android, string, spinner, subscript-operator

I am using a spinner with some text (String) and I would like to write the chemical expression MgCl2 with the number 2 subscripted. How can I do it?

I have seen some posts telling about to use Html.fromHtml() but AndroidStudio says this method is deprecated.
You can see my code below.

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("MgCl2");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly with a [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("MgCl2");
s.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 5, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Your `ArrayAdapter` can be typed as `<CharSequence>`.  Any downstream `setText` calls can take a CharSequence argument (instead of the `String` you're using now).

Note that `SpannableString` is immutable.  For more complex constructions, you may want [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html).

Probably, you should be aware of the set of [`CharacterStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) subclasses.  They represent all the effects you can apply to a [`Spanned`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) of any concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to create text with a subscript. Something along the lines of:

```
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder("MgCl2");
span.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 4, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

This will make the 2 a subscript, however it will retain it's size. To make it smaller add a `RelativeSizeSpan` as well like this:

```
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 3, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

You'll have to change your `ArrayList` type though, to either `CharSequence` or `StringBuilder`

Comment: You only need to use `SpannableStringBuilder` if the String content is mutable.  If you know your String is constant, you can use `SpannableString`, for which only the markup is mutable.